# How can I write an extension method that converts a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a byte array?

Tags: .net, bitmap, gdi+, extension-methods

How can I write an extension method that converts a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a byte array?  Why not:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ToByteArray(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Bitmap) As Byte()
    Using ms = New MemoryStream()
        image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat)
        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

Yet when I use that, I get "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+" thrown from the Save() operation.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the "end using" line is ever being triggered due to the return statement, so something is not being cleaned up properly.

Also, try experimenting with closing the stream before you convert it to an array.

Comment: @Mathias: `using` blocks in .Net still work as expected even when you `return` from them, so that's not this guy's problem.

Comment: @Mathias, at least in C# regardless of where you return inside a using, the dispose method is triggered.  Cannot speak for VB.NET, but I'd presume it's the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone else state, this is a known GDI+ bug.

However, it usually appear when you've closed the *source* stream of the image before reading it completely. Just loading a new Image object will only load metadata, like width, height, color depth, etc, not the actual pixels. They will be lazily loaded at a later time.

This can be avoided by copying your image (during loading) into a new Image created in memory. I presume that the input stream is still available at that time. Once you have the new memory-based Image class you can dispose of the source stream freely. (Another solution would be not to close/dispose the source stream).

Edit:
Problem described in [KB814675 Bitmap and Image constructor dependencies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675) together with a workaround.

> **Create a Non-Indexed Image**
>
> This approach requires that the new image be in a non-indexed pixel format (more than 8 bits-per-pixel), even if the original image was in an indexed format. This workaround uses the Graphics.DrawImage() method to copy the image to a new Bitmap object:
>
> 1. Construct the original Bitmap from the stream, from the memory, or from the file.
> 2. Create a new Bitmap of the same size, with a pixel format of more than 8 bits-per-pixel (BPP).
> 3. Use the Graphics.FromImage() method to obtain a Graphics object for the second Bitmap.
> 4. Use Graphics.DrawImage() to draw the first Bitmap onto the second Bitmap.
> 5. Use Graphics.Dispose() to dispose of the Graphics.
> 6. Use Bitmap.Dispose() to dispose of the first Bitmap.
>
> **Create an Indexed Image**
>
> This workaround creates a Bitmap object in an indexed format:
>
> 1. Construct the original Bitmap from the stream, from the memory, or from the file.
> 2. Create a new Bitmap with the same size and pixel format as the first Bitmap.
> 3. Use the Bitmap.LockBits() method to lock the whole image for both Bitmap objects in their native pixel format.
> 4. Use either the Marshal.Copy function or another memory copying function to copy the image bits from the first Bitmap to the second Bitmap.
> 5. Use the Bitmap.UnlockBits() method to unlock both Bitmap objects.
> 6. Use Bitmap.Dispose() to dispose of the first Bitmap.

Comment: That seems to be the problem.  Any suggestions on how to copy a Bitmap to a Bitmap?  Seems that Bitmap's constructor New(Image) actually changes the bitmap to a different format. Or is there another way to get Bitmap to eager-load?

Comment: Take your source stream, copy it to a MemoryStream, load from that and _dont_ dispose of the MemoryStream. The created Image class will still keep a reference to it, and it will be disposed of when your Image is.

Comment: But that violates rule CA2000 and thus I can't deploy.  Any other ideas? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx)

Comment: I've edited by an answer to include information from KB814675 which describes your problem, and possible workaround.

Comment: +1: Thanks for reminding us all about these horrible pitfalls :)

Comment: OK, so it seems that EITHER you let the memorystream stay open until the system garbage-collects it, OR you do one of the copy/redraw dances above--effectively reading every byte of the image twice.  Seems like System.Drawing.Bitmap could use some enhancement to provide a more robust way of doing this. Thanks for the persistence here.

Answer (score 1):

Known GDI+ bug.

You can't close the `MemoryStream` straight away.

Copy the output array to another byte array, then close the stream.

Comment: Didn't work.  When debugging, I see that the exception is thrown from the call to Save(Stream, ImageFormat), not afterward.

Comment: What is the image type? How was it created? What is the pixelformat?

Comment: JPEG at 24bppRGB.  It was created from a byte array converted to a stream and passed into the Bitmap(Stream) constructor.

Comment: @Patrick: See my answer. You've closed that original stream already, which makes your Image object unable to load the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `image.RawFormat` to something like JPEG or PNG.  It's possible for some images to be openable by a Bitmap but not saveable (at least in the original format).

Comment: Tried explicitly specifying JPEG (since that's what my test bitmap is); no change.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread, I using following code and it work correctly:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(ms))
    {
        var bitmapCopy = new Bitmap(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        return bitmapCopy;
    }
}
```