# C# A generic error occurred in GDI+ exceptional error

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am facing this error to save a image in database
kindly share me some solution
thanx in advance

```
string objImage = Path.GetFullPath(objPB.Picture);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(objImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();

byte[] objbyte = imageToByteArray(img);


public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)    
{    
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   return ms.ToArray();    
}
```

Comment: what's in your `imageIn`? are you sure it's a valid image?

Comment: Seems like a known GDI+ bug, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671449/how-can-i-write-an-extension-method-that-converts-a-system-drawing-bitmap-to-a-b)

Comment: This has been asked many times and has also been answered many times. You could just have searched SO for "GDI+ generic error".