# How to convert PictureBoxImage to byte array

Tags: c#, image, binary

How can I convert a `PictureBox.Image` to byte array to store in database directly ..

I tried the following code but they all give me the same error  " a generic error occurred  in GDI + "

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));    
}


public byte[] convertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); 
         // or whatever output format you like
         return ms.ToArray(); 
     }
}
```

P.S I am running the program as Administrator too

Comment: Have you already closed your image (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671449/how-can-i-write-an-extension-method-that-converts-a-system-drawing-bitmap-to-a-b))?

Comment: I would get bitmap from image first...and then unlock it? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits(v=vs.110).aspx