# GDI+ Generic Error

Tags: c#-4.0

When my images are being loaded from my database on my web server, I see the following error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   EncoderParameters encoderParams)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)    at
>   MyWeb.Helpers.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

All my code is attempting to do is load the image, can anybody take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Note - This works if I test it on my local machine, but not when I deploy it to my web server.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Clear();          

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["imageid"]))         
    {
        int imageID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["imageid"]);
        int isThumbnail = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["thumbnail"]);

        // Retrieve this image from the database
        Image image = GetImage(imageID);

        // Make it a thumbmail if requested
        if (isThumbnail == 1)
        {
            Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
            image = image.GetThumbnailImage(200, 200, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";             

        // Save the image to the OutputStream             
        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }         
    else         
    {             
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";             
        context.Response.Write("<p>Error: Image ID is not valid - image may have been deleted from the database.</p>");         
    } 
}
```

The error occurs on the line:

> image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);

**UPDATE**

I've changed my code to this, bit the issue still happens:

```
var db = new MyWebEntities();

var screenshotData = (from screenshots in db.screenshots
                      where screenshots.id == imageID
                      select new ImageModel
                      {
                           ID = screenshots.id,
                           Language = screenshots.language,
                           ScreenshotByte = screenshots.screen_shot,
                           ProjectID = screenshots.projects_ID
                      });

foreach (ImageModel info in screenshotData) 
 {
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(info.ScreenshotByte))
    {
         Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

         // Make it a thumbmail if requested
         if (isThumbnail == 1)
         {
              Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
              image = image.GetThumbnailImage(200, 200, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
         }

         context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

         // Save the image to the OutputStream             
         image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    } }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably for the same reason that [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream) was having problems - because the for a lifetime of an Image constructed from a `Stream`, the stream must not be destroyed.

So if your `GetImage` function constructs the returned image from a stream (e.g. a `MemoryStream`) and then closes the stream before returning the image then the above will fail.  My guess is that your `GetImage` looks a tad like this:

```
Image GetImage(int id)
{
    byte[] data = // Get data from database
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(data);
    }
}
```

If this is the case then try having `GetImage` return the `MemoryStream` (or possibly the byte array) directrly so that you can create the `Image` instance in your `ProcessRequest` method and dispose of the stream only when the processing of that image has completed.

This is mentioned in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) but its kind of in the small print.

Comment: Hi Justin, I think I've changed my code to avoid this, but I still see the issue - could you take a look in my updated question? Also, it's weird that this works on my dev box, but not when I deploy it to a server?

Comment: @JimmyC Not sure then, are the images **very** large? GDI+ seems to impose a height limit of 64K.  Alternatively do you know if this only happens for thumbnails?  Also can you be sure that `ThumbnailCallback` is not throwing an exception?

Comment: The images are quite small. This happens on both thumbnails & normal size images. It seems to me like a config issue, due to the fact it works on my local machine, but I'm not sure what type of config issue could cause this error.