# Save chart as image without using existing method

Tags: asp.net

How can I save my chart in image format without using it's existing 4 methods (saveimage())

I have to implement my custom method.

```
    public new void SaveImage(string Path)
    {

    }
```

I have to hide existing method.

Comment: What kind of chart? More info

Comment: how can i implement IChartStorageHandler's  load method for chart genration.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to hide the existing Save methods? What is so specific in your scenario?

Regards,
Evgenia

Comment: I am getting GDI+ error ,which is invoke by save method but i am not calling this method any where in the project.

Comment: You may find this discussed in another thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream. I hope the suggestions there are helpful.

Comment: it was not helpful for me, I need to implement httpimage handler for image rendering and saving

Comment: how can i implement IChartStorageHandler's load method for chart genration