# how i can save image in picturebox without generic error

Tags: c#, image, gdi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

I have a `PictureBox` that has it's image loaded from database.

```
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader[13]);
pbShenasname.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(ms2);
ms2.Close();
```

i want to save this image from `PictureBox` to a path in local hard drive by doing:

```
if (SFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    pbShenasname.Image.Save(SFD.FileName,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

SFD is a saveFileDialog.

When i try this code get me an error for generic error GDI. 
How i can save it without errors?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: a generic error occurred in 'GDI+'

Comment: maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream) can help

Comment: do you try Bitmap.Save() method with different encoding parameter?

Comment: yes and problem solved. tnx