# copy an image and save it to other directory

Tags: c#, winforms

I am beginner in c#. In my project, if I do try the below code to save a copy of image, it is giving error "A generic error occurred in GDI+." . I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053052/1577396), but I have no knowledge of what is he saying.

I tried the below code:

```
 Bitmap bmpLarge = new Bitmap(ofdFlagsLarge.FileName);
 bmpLarge.Save(@"\..\..\" + strLargePath);               /* ERROR */
```

Can someone please assist me to save a image from the local PC directory itself to other directory on the same machine..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just want to copy a file?

Why not use:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

Comment: Adding to @middelpat's answer-
System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination",true); This will overwrite if there is any file with the same name.