# Generating a 4–8 digit random number

Tags: c#, random

```
Random random = new Random();
int password = random.Next(10000);
```

This generates 2-digit and 3-digit numbers also. How do I generate a 4–8 digit random number in C#?

Comment: see the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539974/random-number-generator-c-sharp[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539974/random-number-generator-c-sharp

Comment: For your purposes, is **0004** a 4-digit number? Is **00000008** an 8-digit number? Does it matter that those are included?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Start at the smallest 4-digit number, end at the smallest 9-digit number (exclusive):

```
int password = random.Next(1000, 100000000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also make a method:

```
public static int GetRandom(int minDigits, int maxDigits)
{
    if (minDigits < 1 || minDigits > maxDigits)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    return (int)random.Next(Math.Pow(10, minDigits - 1), Math.Pow(10, maxDigits - 1));
}
```

Comment: You could, but why would you ever do that?

Answer (score 3):

To cover all your bases (numbers under 1000 such as 0002)

```
Random RandomPIN = new Random();
var RandomPINResult = RandomPIN.Next(0, 9999).ToString();
RandomPINResult = RandomPINResult.PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: Why not: 
`Random RandomPIN = new Random(); 
var RandomPINResult = RandomEASPIN.Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4");`

Answer (score 2):

new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4")

Comment: It uses the classical random value, but the author was aware that a seed is needed to get real random values. So the next step is just to generate an int from an interval and make sure it's formatted with pre-pending (pad left) zeros (4 digit length).