# Distributing and there is some problems

Tags: c#

I will be distributing my program. It will take pictures and save them to a folder. The problem is: `C:/Users/G73/Desktop/`

Everyone has there own file path... In the code it is

```
bitmap.Save("C:/Users/G73/Desktop/My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It has my File path and the name of my computer... How would I make it to change to the users path?

Comment: Try `%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(path, "My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It gets Desktop path for current user. You can get more special folders using [`Enviroment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: Personal opinion - `MyDocuments` or `MyPictures` are probably better choices than dumping random stuff on desktop...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point, that's why I mentioned other SpecialFolders :)

Comment: @DevonFelix what is in inner exception?

Comment: @DevonFelix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream it's not caused by this path

Comment: @DevonFelix this does not provide any further information, it's some error in `Drawing.dll` try checking if image you are passing is correct

Comment: I press the take picture button in my program and it doesnt take the picture it just crashes and presents me with an error. I tried implementing something but still no help. :(

Comment: @DevonFelix You need to investigate which line throws exception and why. Try 1. Debug line by line 2. Catch exception

Comment: Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException

Comment: The Problem Is bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(path, "My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg); Idk why its a valid path and all the restrictions and stuff are off

Answer (score 2):

To get the user's desktop -

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Which you would use with a Path.Combine - e.g.:

```
bitmap.Save (Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK...
```

Though for images you'd likely be better off using the My Pictures directory -

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would I implement that? I am a Noob! Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm using pictures now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
```