# Error : A generic error occurred in GDI+. while saving Image

Tags: c#, .net

While i am trying to save Image getting this error
`A generic error occurred in GDI+`
 I searched for this error and checked write permissions for this folder ,and also checked that image file is not in use by anything else (including my code) But While I am trying to save Image still getting same error,Where is the mistake

```
public partial class AdsMaster : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd=null;
        public AdsMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp";
        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image img = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);//create the bitmap
            string imgName = ofd.SafeFileName;
            txtImagePath.Text = imgName;
            pictureBox1.Image = img.GetThumbnailImage(350, 350, null, new IntPtr());
            ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
            img.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void saveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string path = str + "\\Image\\";
        Image img = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
        string imgName = ofd.SafeFileName;
        try
        {
               img.Save(path + imgName); //getting error at this line 
               MessageBox.Show("Image is saved");
               img.Dispose();  // dispose of your image                   
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
        }

      }        
}
```

Comment: Check the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream?rq=1

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to save the image to the same file it was loaded from (is the image file in the application directory)?

Comment: I tried saving it from another Folder ,still getting same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here may be due to the fact that a lock is placed on the original image when you call

```
Image img = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
```

The following should do the trick

```
private void saveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string path = str + "\\Image\\";
    string imgName = ofd.SafeFileName;

    try
    {
        File.Copy(ofd.FileName, path + imgName);

        MessageBox.Show("Image is saved");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, helped me out! Though all I had to do was make a new Bitmap from the existing one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream/33324011#33324011

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this error by changing the file name and path to where the file is stored.
You needs to check either one of them-

1- FileName should be different/ should not get matched with other files name which have been already present on that location where new file/image you want to store.

2- change the (save ) location of the new file from operating system drive.
try to avoid to store the new file/Image on a drive on which operating system has been already installed.

Below code works for me

```
         IWebdriver driver;
         driver = new ChromeDriver("G:\\Selenium_Csharp\\Jar\\chromedriver_win32"); 
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
         driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

         Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        ss.SaveAsFile("e:\\pande", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```