# c# save bitmap to file, save directory error?

Tags: c#, bitmap, save

I have got a bitmap i would like to save to disk, however i have only managed to save it in same directory as the program exe.

This is the only way i got it to work:

```
image.save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I would like to save it somewhere else on the disk regardless of where the program exe is.
none of these works, i get: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

```
image.save("C:\\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image.save(@"C:\\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

EDIT: btw is it possible to make folders too?
something like this? (i get the same error as always..)

```
image.save("foldername/img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

EDIT2: got it to save to a folder only if the folder allready exists.
Could there be a permission thing? anything that needs to be imported?

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting ?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50868481/fd.png

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
image.save("C:/img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Hopefully these can help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/283361/A-generic-error-occurred-in-GDIplus, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream

Answer (score 4):

According to [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) pattern definition, you should use ***'/'*** insted of ***'\'*** in resource location path, so:

```
image.save(@"C:/img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  The quick workaround was to manually create the directory and it worked like a champ:

```
string directory_where_you_want_to_save_file = "./subdir";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
image.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\img.jpg");