# A Generic error occurred in GDI+ while saving image to file system

Tags: c#, .net

I have made one desktop application and it throws an error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

Here is my code:

```
   //Generating Images
                    string newpath = "Thumbs";
                    var _path = Path.Combine(_imagesPath, newpath);
                    var thumbFilePath = GetPictureLocalPath(thumbFileName, _path);//"C:\\Users\\Developer\\Documents\\Server2\\Solr Plugin Branch Nop-310\\Presentation\\Nop.Web\\Content\\Images\\Thumbs\\"+thumbFileName;
                    if (!File.Exists(thumbFilePath))
                    {
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(pictureBinary))
                        {
                            Bitmap b = null;

                            //try-catch to ensure that picture binary is really OK. Otherwise, we can get "Parameter is not valid" exception if binary is corrupted for some reasons
                          //  b = new Bitmap(stream);

                            try
                            {
                                //try-catch to ensure that picture binary is really OK. Otherwise, we can get "Parameter is not valid" exception if binary is corrupted for some reasons
                                b = new Bitmap(stream);
                            }
                            catch (ArgumentException exc)
                            {
                                string msg =  exc.ToString();
                                string fullmsg = string.Format("Error generating picture thumb. ID={0}", pictureId);
                                InsertSystemLog(msg, fullmsg);
                            }


                            if (b == null)
                            {
                                //bitmap could not be loaded for some reasons
                                return url;
                            }
                            var newSize = CalculateDimensions(b.Size, _productThumbPictureSize);

                            if (newSize.Width < 1)
                                newSize.Width = 1;
                            if (newSize.Height < 1)
                                newSize.Height = 1;

                            using (var newBitMap = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height))
                            {
                                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitMap))
                                {
                                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                                    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                                    g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
                                    var ep = new EncoderParameters();
                                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 80L);
                                    ImageCodecInfo ici = GetImageCodecInfoFromExtension(lastPart);
                                    if (ici == null)
                                        ici = GetImageCodecInfoFromMimeType("image/jpeg");
                                    try
                                    { newBitMap.Save(thumbFilePath, ici, ep); }
                                    catch (ArgumentException exc)
                                    {
                                        string msg = exc.ToString();
                                        string fullmsg = string.Format("Unable to save Picture ID={0}", pictureId);
                                        InsertSystemLog(msg, fullmsg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

I have seen one answer at this link about permission: [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

But this is a console application. So which permission I need to give to generate Images on file system.

Please can anyone help.

Comment: Which line throws an exception?

Comment: Does the path exists? The folder you are trying to create the file should already exist.

Comment: Following line:
b = new Bitmap(stream);

Comment: @Mathew: Yes, folder already exist

Comment: @Ankita: what's the content of the 'pictureBinary' ?

Comment: @HABJAN: picturebinary is a byte type variable

Comment: @Ankita: I figured that out, but what I would like to know if that byte array represents a valid bitmap? Can you save that byte array to the disk, name it as appropriate image format and try to open it via some picture viewer?

Comment: @HABJAN: Sorry, but I did not get you..:-(

Comment: @Ankita: how do you make 'pictureBinary' where do you get this byte array from?

Comment: @HABJAN: I am fetching picture binary from image by this line of code: File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); //filepath is where the image exist

Comment: @Ankita: Can you try to load that file directly to the bitmap, like: Bitmap b = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);

Comment: @HABJAN: Okay, I will try and inform you soon

Comment: File.Exists() is not good enough to check that you can create the file.  My crystal ball says that the directory you are saving to doesn't exist.

Comment: @HABJAN: Still it throws same error. May be some permission issue? But I do not know to to which account I give write permission

Comment: @Ankita: can you locate that image on the disk via Windows Explorer and try to open it in some image viewer? What format is this image?

Comment: create thumbfilepath folder in  "if(!File.Exists(thumbfilepath))" first.