# A generic error occurred in GDI+, Saving non png image from Fileupoad FileBytes to MemoryStream

Tags: file-upload, gdi+, memorystream

I have applied the recommended solution for the GDI+ error from here:

[A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

I still does not work for jpeg and jpg files, but works fine for all png

See my actual code below:

```
            Dim fl = uploader.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower

            If fl.EndsWith(".png") OrElse fl.EndsWith(".jpeg") OrElse fl.EndsWith(".jpg") Then
                Using ms = New MemoryStream(uploader.FileBytes)
                    Using i = Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
                        i.Save(ms, If(fl.EndsWith(".png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                        Dim sig = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
                        Dim code = Trim(txtStaff.Text).PadLeft("00000000")
                        DB.rw_signature_save(code, sig)
                    End Using
                End Using

                BuildSignatureList()

                statusBox.Attributes("class") = "notification success"
                statusBox.InnerHtml = "Signature updated succesfully"
            Else
                statusBox.Attributes("class") = "notification warning"
                statusBox.InnerHtml = "Only <b>Image</b> ( <font color='green'>.png, .jpg </font> ) files allowed."
            End If
```

Please is there any other solution to this besides the one linked to above?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just realized this is actually all unnecesary.
I can go straight from uploader.FileBytes to Convert.ToBase64String

```
Dim sig = Convert.ToBase64String(uploader.FileBytes)
```