# A generic error occurred in GDI+ eror

Tags: c#

First am replacing 
      ImagePath_DevSvr= D:\Image.jpeg
      ImagePath_DevSvr_tif=E:\images\1.tif

```
       System.Drawing.Bitmap wiImage1 = null;

   string ReplaceImage_path1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath_DevSvr_tif"];

     wiImage1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath_DevSvr"]);

      wiImage1.Save(ReplaceImage_path1);
```

Second am replacing 
ImagePath_TestSvr= D:\Image.jpeg
ImagePath_TestSvr_tif=F:\images\1.tif

```
        System.Drawing.Bitmap wiImage = null;

       string ReplaceImage_path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath_TestSvr_tif"];

      wiImage = new   System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath_TestSvr"]);

       wiImage.Save(ReplaceImage_path);
```

For first time replacing it is working for second it is not working please help me out Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you dispose the bitmap?..

Comment: Does your application have rights to write to the `C:\Images` path ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream

Comment: wiImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap getting error at this line

Comment: Yes my application have the rights

Comment: Now am not getting any error but i didnt do any changes can any one tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Image.FromFile` instead.

```
Bitmap wiImage = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"]);
```

Comment: please help me now again am getting the exception

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap wiImage = null;

Comment: What exception do you get at the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why it now works

- Images\Image.jpg did not exist and then you created/saved it
- You never saved the app.config file that had the app settings