# Why can't I create an image from image array

Tags: c#, image

I'm getting an error very similar to [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

However, I don't believe I'm shutting down the stream and as such, the answers don't apply

Please consider

```
var img = (Tests.Properties.Resources.image).ToByteArray(); //img is a png;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
    var pic = Image.FromStream(ms);
    pic.Save(this._absolutePath, this._format); //kaboomn
}
```

The issue is the final line of code goes kaboom!

> "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

This is the extension method

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Bitmap image)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

So, although I'm using 2 streams, the first time returns the bytes and as such, I'm not using the same stream, I'm simply working with the bytes.

Comment: check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814675/bitmap-and-image-constructor-dependencies

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fne with png image. Perhaps your path or output format are not valid.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin, that is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
    var pic = Image.FromStream(ms);
    pic.Save(this._absolutePath, this._format);
}
```

to

```
var pic = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(img)));
pic.Save(this._absolutePath, this._format);
```

Check this [Bitmap and Image constructor dependencies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814675/bitmap-and-image-constructor-dependencies)