# Why do I get an error when saving image of a form to file in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, file, graphics

I need to save an image of my application's form to a picture file, like a jpeg, bmp, or png, etc.

Numerous sources on the internet give this or similar code examples for capturing an image of a form:

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height))
    End Using
    Return tmpImg
End Function
```

and this to save the image of the form captured by that code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TakeScreenShot(Me).Save("c:\My Folder\Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

The code for capturing the form's image seems to work (does not result in an error) but the line of code saving the image to file gives this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in >System.Drawing.dll
> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I have tried variations of the code, but in all cases the statement for saving the image to file

```
.Save("c:\My Folder\Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

always gives the exception error. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the user account the program is running under have write permission to the directory you want to save to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

Comment: Your question about write permissions gave me the solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) I think that you can accept the duplicate suggestion to get this question closed, to help keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew pointed out it is most likely a permission problem.  I did it this way so you could try different locations.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tmpImg As Bitmap = TakeScreenShot(Me)
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "Screen.png")
    tmpImg.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

Comment: Duh to me for not thinking of that. Your suggestion solved the problem and I would "upvote" it but I don't have enough status here to do that. So I'll just say thanks and hope I don't get in trouble for that :-)

Comment: @DanielRutschman thanks.  Mark as answer if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a rectangle from screen (in bounds of your `Form`) not your `Form` screenshot.
However you have not to save directly from `tmpImage` (as it’s not yet released) but from a source copy of that image.
The code below shows how (one of ways):

```
Using final As Bitmap = New Bitmap(TakeScreenShot(Me))
    final.Save("C:\My Folder\Screenshot.png")
End Using
```